# Problems with RecyclerView height item

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

Sorry for my english, but I have a problem with my recyclerview, It looks great but when I scroll the screen, items resize to match_parent.

Before Scroll:

[image]

After scroll:

[image]

Here is my code:

```
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
   >

    <include
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    layout="@layout/toolbar"></include>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"
    android:id="@+id/recyclerViewNotas"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:clickable="true"
    >

    </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: share your row.xml

Comment: In your row.xml, make sure that height is not hotcoded or matchparent.

Comment: yes, the solution was that i have layout_height match_parent instead wrap_content. :(

Answer (score 1):

Although this question is asked 4 years ago.
I encounter the same question.
The solution to my question is to change the `android:layout_height` of the list item to `wrap_content` from `match_parent`.

Answer (score 0):

The default LinearLayoutManager does not support wrap_content so you need to custom your LinearLayoutManager, pls reference this:

https://gist.github.com/truongngoclinh/a73a113d886ff022b9da